# use angular formcontrolname with div like an input element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I was just curious if anyone was using the formContrlName directive with an editable div or paragraph the same way you would with an input.  Example html:

```
<form>
<section [formGroup]='testForm'>
  <input formControlName='first' name='first'/>
  <div id='second' tabindex='0' contenteditable=true formControlName='second'></div>
</section>
</form>
```

The value of 'first' is in the input element automatically and any changes in the input element are automatically reflected in the form.  Ideally, the content of the div would be the value of the second formcontrol and since it is editable, the form value would be updated automatically, just like the input element.

There are multiple ways to duplicate it the functionality.  I'd just use (blur) and (focus) events to set the div contenteditable=true on focus and update the formcontrol on (blur).

```
<div 
  id='second' 
  tabindex='0' 
  (focus)='makeEditable($event)'
  (blur)='updateForm($event, "testForm.second")'
> 
  {{ testForm.get('second')?.value }}
</div>
```

Typescript pseudocode:

```
public makeEditable(event: unknown): void {
  try {
    event.target.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error setting editable: ', e);
  }
}

public updateForm(event: unknown, control = ''): void {
  try {
    event.target.removeAttribue('contenteditable');
    if (control !== '' && (this.myform.get(control) ?? null) !== null) {
      this.myform.get(control).setValue( (event.target?.innerHTML ?? ''), {
        onlySelf: false,
        emitValue: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error updating value: ', event, control, e);
  }
}
```

I was just curious if there was a built-in way to have all of that happen automagically.

Comment: Unclear why you would want this? You do want the user to actually directly edit the content of the div? If yes, just use an input, if not use string interpolation?

Comment: @MikeOne - the idea is that the page would be just a page of text, and look like it, until a user wanted to edit an entry.  If you swap between text and an input element you have to make sure the css is right or everything shifts around.  Think a list of items in a receipt where you can click edit and change the amount of an item.  But more complicated.

Comment: Gotcha. I’d still solve this with pure css just to prevent the issues (and complexity) you’re seeing..

Comment: Yes, ended up mat-inputs but not showing all of the input specific css unless the item was being edited.  That is indeed the simpler way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking, this was the simplest way to do things.  Html pseudocode:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; i = index">
  <mat-form-field
    id='{{"item-mff-" + i }}'
    [class.readonly-mff]='(isEditing[i] ?? false) === false'
    [class.block-mouse]='(isEditing[i] ?? false) === false'
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      formControlName="fc"
      [class.readonly-input]='(isEditing[i] ?? false) === false'
      [class.block-mouse]='(isEditing[i] ?? false) === false'
      readonly
    />
  </mat-form-field>
  <button
    (click)='editItem(i)'
  >
    Edit
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

In your component.ts file, isEditing is an Array.  editItem(i) does document.getElementById('item-mff-' + i) and then removes the readonly attribute from the input.  There are actually about 10 fields for the item, so it does all of them.  It sets this.isEditing[i]=true so the appropriate classes are applied.  What you do in your css will depend on what style of mat-form-field you use and how you want it to look.  The block-mouse class's style sets pointer-events: none because not all form controls allow readonly.  And if you are using a mat-autocomplete with your input, while the input is readonly you can still trigger the mat-autocomplete by clicking on it.